Set a simple password less than 8 characters
I wanted to set a password less than 8 characters actually a 4 simple digit password.
Just like we do in fedora-
sudo passwd lamy
I am searching for an alternative to that to do the same in ubuntu 24.10.
current output for passwd

This might help: How do you set requirements (such as minimum length) on passwords?

What happened when you tried that in Ubuntu?

I regularly do install QA tests using the password "please" and don't have issues, in fact often do use a 4 letter password too; so I don't see your problem. You don't mention what Ubuntu product you're using (only specifying release being 24.04 for which 3 installers are available) so different installers maybe involved; but post install I can't see why you can't EVEN if your unstated installer doesn't allow it during install.

Currently on ubuntu desktop 24.10 I have edited the post for the output of passwd

@terdon the article unfortunately didn't help, I tried it as per the guide but the output is still the same

Have you tried just elevating privileges (ie. using sudo and of course specifying $USER to impact to deal with use of sudo) ; as the BAD PASSWORD message in that case will be a warning only & ignored.. so as long you type it twice correctly, it'll be accepted.  That has always worked for me (just tested on my 24.10 & it works here too!)

Please don't post images of text. Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the formatting tools to format it as code.

Elevate your privileges using sudo.
eg. my username ($USER) is guiverc so I could do that via
guiverc@d7050-next:~$   sudo passwd guiverc
[sudo] password for guiverc: 
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully

I just typed my shorter password in twice (I used four letters; being the passwd I use often in QA I mentioned in comment) and it worked.
My system is currently using oracular or 24.10, as the next development release isn't setup fully yet, so this was tested on 24.10 too.
The BAD PASSWORD message is thus a warning that can be ignored...
You could also use sudo password $USER if you didn't know your username, but I just typed guiverc in my test.

it shows successfull but isn't actually changing the password
edit: IT WORKED...
after a restart the password is changed...
THANK YOU SO MUCH

it wasn't a restart that was required; if you were using a logged in terminal; a restart of the terminal may have be sufficient, or if using a GUI session, restart of that session (ie. logout & login again)...   The restart was just a more dramatic way of restarting your session settings to reflect your recent change.  In my testcase; it worked perfectly including changing back, but I no doubt tested it differently to how you tried; as I'd have tested it (unconsciously most likely doubt) in a way where I expected it to work.

On my 24.04 this doesn't work... I'm pretty sure I didn't change my /etc/pam.d/common-password or my /etc/security/pwquality.conf (although I couldn't swear on that) and my /etc/pam.d/common-password contains password requisite pam_pwquality.so retry=3. pam_pwquality's minlen defaults to 8 if unspecified, and I have enforce_for_root set in  /etc/security/pwquality.conf, which explains why it doesn't work. Has this changed in 24.10? Do you mind sharing if your /etc/security/pwquality.conf contains enforce_for_root?

oooo I could have just avoided all that by just logging out and log back in... guiverc Man you're a genius....

@kos, this install was made during the mantic cycle (daily Xubuntu 20230829) so I'd not expect any change; with birthdate of file 2023-08-29 (matching ISO) but access today; so I don't believe it's been changed... contents at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qF9B9562Nb/

Thanks! I'll spin up a 24.04 VM later, now I'm curious, I may have changed /etc/security/pwquality.conf for some reason. Cause I too remember the behavior you're getting on 24.10
